Neovim treesitter setup issue in init.lua
This is my setup file:
vim.cmd("set expandtab")
vim.cmd("set tabstop=2")
vim.cmd("set softtabstop=2")
vim.cmd("set shiftwidth=2")
vim.g.mapleader = " "

local lazypath = vim.fn.stdpath("data") .. "/lazy/lazy.nvim"
if not (vim.uv or vim.loop).fs_stat(lazypath) then
  vim.fn.system({
    "git",
    "clone",
    "--filter=blob:none",
    "https://github.com/folke/lazy.nvim.git",
    "--branch=stable", -- latest stable release
    lazypath,
  })
end
vim.opt.rtp:prepend(lazypath)

local plugins = {
  { "catppuccin/nvim", name = "catppuccin", priority = 1000 },
  {
    'nvim-telescope/telescope.nvim', tag = '0.1.6',
    dependencies = { 'nvim-lua/plenary.nvim' }
  },
  {
    "nvim-treesitter/nvim-treesitter",
    build = ":TSUpdate",
    config = function()
        require("nvim-treesitter.configs").setup {
            ensure_installed = "all",
            highlight = {
                enable = true,
            },
            indent = {
                enable = true,
            }
        }
    end
  },
}
local opts = {}

require("lazy").setup(plugins, opts)
local builtin = require("telescope.builtin")
vim.keymap.set('n', '<C-p>', builtin.find_files, {})
vim.keymap.set('n', '<leader>fg', builtin.live_grep, {})


require("catppuccin").setup()
vim.cmd.colorscheme "catppuccin"

When I replace nvim-treesitter part inside the plugins variable, it works. Here's what I replace it with:
{"nvim-treesitter/nvim-treesitter", build = ":TSUpdate"}

Here's what I see when I try to run nvim .\init.lua

I'm using Windows, NeoVim version 0.9.5, LuaJIT 2.1
